# create new user, MyAccountManager.create_user() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a django application. And I am using the django-restframework. And I try to create a user witch the user has to enter two times a password. But if I do a post, after when I have filled in the data:

```
{
  "email": "user@example.com",
  "username": "string",
  "password": "string",
  "password2": "string"
}
```

Then I get this error:

```
TypeError at /api/user/create/
MyAccountManager.create_user() got an unexpected keyword argument 'password2'
```

So this is my create method :

```
from django.contrib.auth import (get_user_model, authenticate)
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    """Serializer for the account object"""
    
    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)
    
    
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields=['email',  'username', 'password','password2' ]
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'min_length':5}}
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create user"""  
        
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
        
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError( {'error': 'P1 and P2 are not the same'})   

       return get_user_model().objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

and this is how the view looks:

```
class CreateUserView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """_summary_:Create a new user in the system

    Args:
        generics (_type_): _description_
    """
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
```

Question: how to resolve this?

I have it now like:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    """Serializer for the account object"""
    
    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)
    
    
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields=['email',  'username', 'password','password2' ]
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'min_length':5}}
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create user"""  
        
        password = self.validated_data['password']        
        
        if password != self.validated_data.pop('password2'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError( {'error': 'P1 and P2 are not the same'})       
        
        
        
        return get_user_model().objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

But I get still this error:

```
TypeError at /api/user/create/
MyAccountManager.create_user() got an unexpected keyword argument 'password2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MyAccountManager.create_user` does not have a `password2` parameter, you should add it there or pop it from the `validated_data` after you check it equals to pwd1 in the `AccountSerializer.create`.

```py
from django.contrib.auth import (get_user_model, authenticate)
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    """Serializer for the account object"""
    
    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)
    
    
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields=['email',  'username', 'password','password2' ]
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'min_length':5}}
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create user"""  
        
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
        
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError( {'error': 'P1 and P2 are not the same'})  
 
        self.validated_data.pop('password2')  # throw away the pwd2

       return get_user_model().objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

Or even neater:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create user"""  

        password = self.validated_data['password']

        if password != self.validated_data.pop('password2'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError( {'error': 'P1 and P2 are not the same'})  

       return get_user_model().objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```